# VSO Code for Azure Data-bricks Note Books

Tags: visual-studio-code, databricks, azure-databricks

Can anyone help me regarding Building an VSO Code in Visual Studio for Azure Data Bricks notebooks for building code in visual Studio.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may use Visual Studio Code extension that allows you to work with Azure Databricks and Databricks on AWS locally in an efficient way, having everything you need integrated into VS Code.

It can be downloaded from the official Visual Studio Code extension gallery: [Databricks VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=paiqo.databricks-vscode)

Comment: I have already added that extension but i want to know how to link my azure data bricks with VScode.

Comment: @HiranyaSrikanth You may refer "Setup and Configuration" in Databricks VSCode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=paiqo.databricks-vscode

Comment: @HiranyaSrikanth, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.